# Is it possible to get a 4 digit pin from this?

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics

[This is the problem to be solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMjsp.png)

This just came across my social media feed and my first thought was "haha funny" but then I tried playing around with the equation and didn't see a way to get a 4 digit pin. Is it possible to pull a 4 digit pinout of this equation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Finally, do not post pictures of text. Type your question out and for formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.

Comment: Well, you’d have to evaluate it, presumably finding a number with at least four decimal places. I’m afraid this is not a do-it-for-me forum, so you’ll have to try to evaluate this integral, show your workings, etc. If you want a response.

Comment: The question made me lol. Funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be happy if you show your step - by - step solution for me to help you in which parts that you not understand or cannot solve.

For conclusion, the final answer is : -2.981266944005536....
So, if first 4 digit, then the pin will be : 2981 
So, if first 4 decimal digit, then the pin will be : 9812

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that! I thought I had lost it.